# "Create an Account" Button sends user to Home page

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl

When the user clicks the "**Create an Account**" button on the login page, instead of being directed to the account creation page they are taken to the home page.

> I cannot see any reason for this, this feature used to work. I can
>   only guess that it has something to do with the **SSL
>   implementation**. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Admin setting to redirect on My account page after login,

**System >> Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Login options > Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in > Yes**

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the SSL. I've seen similar behavior because of it.

Inspect the URL that the "Create an Account" button links to - does it start with https?

If it does not - ensure that you've enabled "Use Secure URLs in Frontend" in
 System > Configuration > Web, under "Secure" tab and that the "Base URL" and "Base Link URL" do have https.

If that still does not work and you're hosting on apache you can try adding this into the .htaccess and see if it helps.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```